# How to get only the changed part of the file to be proccessed in pre-commit hook?

Tags: bash, git, shell, pre-commit-hook

I used the following shell script in pre-commit hooks,to get only the modified lines of a cpp file which is to be commit in git. But it is giving entire file which has changed lines. How could i get only the changed lines of a file to process for pre-commit check.

Here is the script which i used:

```
changed_files=$(git diff-index --cached $against | \
    grep -E '[MA]   .*\.(c|cpp|cc|cxx)$' | cut -f 2)
```

Comment: try `git add -p` and you can choose which lines of changed files you want to commit

Comment: @d0niek Interactive `git add` in pre-commit hook?!

Comment: `git diff --cached`, no?

Comment: I tried adding git add -p and git diff --cached. changed_file itself is not coming properly.

Comment: This is how my code looks like
if git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1
then
 against=HEAD
else
 # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
 against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
fi
exec 1>&2
changed_files=$(git diff-index --cached $against | \
 grep -E '[MA] .*\.(c|cpp|cc|cxx)$' | cut -f 2)

Comment: Can you add an example of the expected output?

Comment: The variable `changed_files` shall contain a list of changed files, right?

Answer (score 3):

[`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) `--cached` should show you the staged changes only.

I guess what you are looking for is:

```
git diff --cached --name-status | grep -E '[MAD] *.*\.(c|cpp|cc|cxx)$' | cut -f2
```

Also, you can try adding the `--name-only` option instead of piping the output through `cut`.

```
git diff-index --cached --name-only $against | grep -E '.*\.(c|cpp|cc|cxx)$'
```

Comment: I tried but its not working for me. Any other suggestion please

Comment: @AparnaElangovan What do you mean by "not working"? No output or not the expected output?

Comment: @AparnaElangovan This is very strange. The updated answer should not return the whole file but the file name only. Maybe the issue is somewhere else?

Comment: As it is returning the file name , my pre-commit checks whole file content and not the changed lines alone. I need my pre-commit to check only the changed lines of the file and not the whole file.

Comment: `git diff --cached ` without piping through `grep` and `cut` will give the changed lines.

Answer (score 1):

If said file is staged (i.e. has been `git add`), then you can use `git diff --staged` or `git diff --cached` (both are synonyms).

If you have more than one file staged, you can specify which one you want to look at with `git diff --staged [path/filename]`.

Comment: I tried this but its not working . Any other suggestion please